# excel-vba: Assign bold font to lines in string text

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have a string element that contains several lines of text. If I use this string as an outlook body text though, they will have no format like bold font to specific lines. I would like to take this string and apply bold font to specific lines (e.g. to all which contain the symbol "@" with a for loop).

How can I implement that in my code before I incorporate the string as body text of my e-mail? I guess I must create a new object out of it and get that one instead into the body of the e-mail.

```
 Sub Send_Email()
 Dim OutApp As Object
 Dim OutMail As Object

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 OutApp.Session.Logon
 Dim iFile As Integer
 Dim strVar As String 'Pre-definition of the input variable

 iFile = FreeFile

 Open "FILE_PATH" For Input As #iFile
 strVar = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile) 'Definition of the input varibale
 Close #iFile

 Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
 On Error Resume Next

 With OutMail
 .To = ""
 .BCC = ""
 .Subject = ""    
 .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
 .Body = strVar 'Creation of the e-mail text body
 .Display 'Or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you would use WordEditor to manipulate the text. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the HTMLBody property to a properly formatted HTML text:

```
strvar = "<html><body>some <b>bold</b> text<br>and <i>italic</i> too</body></html>"
...
.HTMLBody = strVar
```

Comment: well my strVar consists already of text pieces. I want to assign bold to them, not to write the string myself. The string text is originated by a rtf file

Comment: If it is an RTF file, why not set the RtfBody property?

Comment: Output is gonna be the same, I just tried if HTML would keep the bold fonts

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to bold a string in the active cell if it contains a "@" in it. You'll need to figure out what you need it to do, but this should help get you started. It only works on the active cell as of right now.

```
If ActiveCell.Value Like "*@*" Then
  ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
End If
```

Comment: How can I make something like ActiveCell work for a string? That's the one million dollar question

Comment: I would paste the string where you ant it then bold it

Comment: Is this string with the "@" in them going to be an email or body text?

Comment: In the body text of an email